# PHP array formatting issue

Tags: php

I have an array list like

```
[1] => Array
   (
       [name] => Linda
       [age] => 23
       [country] => USA
   )

[2] => Array
   (
       [name] => Fleur
       [age] => 16
       [country] => France
   )
```

How do I remove the keys [1], [2] from the array so I get an output like

```
Array
   (
       [name] => Linda
       [age] => 23
       [country] => USA
   )

Array
   (
       [name] => Fleur
       [age] => 16
       [country] => France
   )
```

Any help would be appreciated. I know it seems simple but I'm new to this.

Comment: You can do that.You should learn the basic.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to print the output you want, you can just do this:

```
print_r($arr[1]);
print_r($arr[2]);
```

There's really not a `"removal"` option since the `"1"` and `"2"` keys you have there are exist for sorting your other subarrays which have similar keys (like **name**).
It's a kind of overwriting..

Even the simplest array like:

```
$arr = array(5,8);
```

is in fact:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 5
   [1] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 1):

loop though and do each one individually

```
foreach($array as $val) {
    print_r($val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any element of an array is a key-value pair.
So you can't have an item without key.

If it's just a matter of output, please do not use var_dump() as a way to output things to your end-user.

You can simply iterate through your main array with a foreach loop, and display items in a user-friendly way.